# Do UV-B emitting lamps for reptile pets produce vitamin-D in human skin?

Tags: dermatology, vitamin-d, uv-rays

There are those lamps like e.g. "ReptiGlow" for pet reptilians, to keep them healthy, the output being graded e.g. by habitat: jungle (trees somewhat reduce the UV that hits the animals), or desert (full sun exposure).
Alas, I have found nothing about the exact wavelengths those kind of lamps produce, and the exact wavelengths human skin needs to produce vitamin-D.

The example used, "ReptiGlow", claims to mimic the UV mix of the sun, with the same kind of UV-A, UV-B mix.

Can such reptilian lamps actually be used to effectively produce vitamin-D in humans, e.g. countering European Winter, without harmful side effects?
If generally so - how would one determine the needed exposure (lamp output, distance to skin, exposure time)?

Comment: Is this just academic curiosity? Why would anyone consider (mis)using devices of doubtful safety when obtaining sufficient vitamin D safely is trivially simple?

Comment: General curiosity. The idea came from me reading about how UV lamps were used to prevent rickets in children in winter, in the past. Not that common anymore.
I haven't looked into this topic for a while, but from what I remember, for a long time a widely held opinion was that obtaining vit-D via skin was superior to food sources in some ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: UV bulbs for reptiles and tanning beds emit mainly UV-A, which *does not promote vitamin D synthesis but can promote skin cancer.*

**UV light and vitamin D synthesis** ([Skin Cancer Foundation](https://www.skincancer.org/healthy-lifestyle/vitamin-d/make-vitamin-d-not-uv-a-priority)):

> Our bodies manufacture vitamin D when the sun's ultraviolet B (UVB)
>   rays interact with 7-dehydrocholesterol (7-DHC) present in the skin.
>   However, we can produce only a limited amount of vitamin D from UVB.
>   A few minutes at midday are sufficient for many Caucasians...After
>   reaching the production limit, further exposure actually destroys the
>   vitamin, decreasing vitamin D levels.

---

Wavelengths of various **ReptiGlo bulbs** range from 300-640 nm (only UV-A or both UV-A and UV-B), depending on the model; the bulbs have up to 40 Watts ([Exo-terra.com](http://www.exo-terra.com/en/products/linear_fluorescent_bulbs.php)).

Modern **tanning devices** provide mostly UV-A (315-400 nm); the power is 100-200 Watts ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_tanning)).

[FDA.gov](https://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ucm186687.htm) claims that both UV-A and UV-B rays causes DNA damage, which can lead to skin cancer and that **all use of tanning beds increases the risk of skin cancer,** from which one can conclude that the **UV reptile bulbs could do the same.**

According to [Indoor Tanning (American Academy of Dermatology)](https://www.aad.org/media/stats/prevention-and-care):

- Exposure to UV radiation from indoor tanning devices is associated
  with an increased risk of **melanoma** and nonmelanoma skin cancer,
  including **squamous cell carcinoma and basal cell carcinoma.**
- Using indoor tanning beds before age 35 can increase your risk of melanoma, the deadliest form of skin cancer, by 59 percent.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if they can be used, but they shouldn’t. Recently, sun exposure is considered more and more harmful to the skin. This is why for recommended Vitamin D levels, no sun exposure whatsoever is usually assumed, and only intake via diet considered.

> Because ultraviolet rays from the sun and tanning beds can cause skin cancer, the American Academy of Dermatology does not recommend getting vitamin D from sun exposure or indoor tanning.
>
> Source: [American Academy of Dermatology](https://www.aad.org/media/stats/prevention-and-care/vitamin-d-and-uv-exposure)

Comment: Hm, I've read about conflicting studies, some claim that some amount of sun exposure is inversely correlated to development of melanoma.
Tanning beds are geared towards tanning / producing UV-A, which is the band said to cause cancer(?).
Some reptilian lamps output a high UV-B portion (they claim), i.e. the exposure time (to get vit-D) may be reduced, also reducing the exposure to UV-A.
So much for theory. Actual numbers would be nice, but given the weirdness of my question, I guess it requires some luck that someone knows about both, human skin requirements and pet accessories ;)

Comment: @user1847129 Do you have those studies at hand? I can’t imagine the evidence to be conflicting, but I can‘t criticise studies I haven’t read yet either... [UV-A and UV-B are definitely both harmful and exposure time of both kinds is directly proportional to developing melanomas](https://www.skincancer.org/prevention/uva-and-uvb). If an institution like the AAD does not even recommend sun exposure for vitamin D production, I think it is safe to assume that the studies are pretty comprehensive and non-conflicting.

Comment: @user1847129, the [last paragraph of this PubMed article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3046902/) says that sun exposure increases the risk of melanoma in people with sun-sensitive skin types (pale skin, fair hair) and decreases the risk in non-sun-sensitive types. And there are two other common skin cancers: squamous cell and basal cell carcinoma, which are related to sun exposure.